# bash func - how to take the argument before function as parameter

Tags: bash

please rename this post if you can help me find a more accurate title.

here is what i have in my bashrc:

```
export currdate=`date | awk '{print $2$3}'`
loggit (){
   $0 2>&1 | tee /tmp/$currdate.logs
}
```

bassically i want to log the output when i run myscript.sh like this:

```
bash$: myscript.sh 2>&1 | tee /tmp/todaydate.logs
```

but i dont want to do that everytime, what i want is

```
bash$: myscript.sh loggit
```

I dont know how to do this when the function goes **after** an argument so Could you help please?

**UPDATE**
Fixed by doing this:

```
loggit (){
       $1 2>&1 | tee /tmp/$currdate.logs
}
```

and do: (thanks to tripleee)

```
bash$: loggit myscript.sh
```

Comment: You can't. Why do you want to do this, and why isn't `loggit myscript.sh` acceptable?

Comment: You might try `tee /tmp/$(date +%b%m).logs` for a little efficiency, and, depending on your application, `tee -a ...` for safety.

Comment: Please answer your own question and accept the answer if you have found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**
Fixed by doing this:

```
loggit (){
       $1 2>&1 | tee /tmp/$currdate.logs
}
```

and do: (thanks to tripleee)

```
bash$: loggit myscript.sh
```